# How to remove comments in string only on the same line?

Tags: lua

I am working on something that will remove comments from a string, but removes everything even if it's on a different line.

Here's my code

```lua
local s = [==[
local a = true -- sup
local b = false -- [[ sup ]]
]==]

print((s:gsub("%-%-(.+)", "")))
```

It removes everything after the first line because of (.+). So is there a way to only remove the comments on a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[^\n]` in the pattern to match non-newline characters. The parentheses can also be removed because you don't use the capture `%1` in the replacement string.

```lua
local s = [==[
local a = true -- sup
local b = false -- [[ sup ]]
]==]

print((s:gsub("%-%-[^\n\r]+", "")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment, and edit is < 6 chars, so I'll have to make it a new answer.

If a line ends with `--` it won't be matched by `[^\n\r]+`, so it should be `[^\n\r]*`.
Also, it might be good to remove (trailing) whitespace before the comment marker, unless they are needed by the use case.

```
local s = [==[
local a = true -- sup
local b = false -- [[ sup ]]
]==]

print((s:gsub("[ \t]*%-%-[^\n\r]*", "")))
```

Comment: Good improvements – matching empty comments and removing trailing whitespace. I'd note that if a line only contains a comment (with optional whitespace before it), `"%s*%-%-[^\n\r]*"` will match the preceding newline and any whitespace. For instance, it will match `"\t\t\n\t\t-- comment here"` and the `gsub` will replace it with `""`. If that's undesirable, `%s*` in the pattern can be replaced with `[ \t]*`.

Comment: Your absolutely right, cyclaminist. And as they say, if you try to solve a problem with regexps you will just end up with two problems. :-p